# .net twitter get user profile

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, userinfo

I want to get the user profile data on connect to twitter. I managed to connect and get the access token and access token secret using Tweetsharp Lib.
 But trying to get the user profile throw an error regarding data type int being too small:

> An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in
>   Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: JSON integer 2537698177 is too large or small
>   for an Int32. Path 'status.in_reply_to_user_id', line 1, position 763.

which is a bug inside their dll. 
Can anybody tell me another way or show an example of getting the user info once you have the access token after connect?

this is the code I am using Tweetsharp dll:

```
var service = new TwitterService(Storage.TwitterConsumerKey, Storage.TwitterConsumerSecret);

            service.AuthenticateWith(sAccessToken, sAccessTokenSecret);

            var userProfile = service.BeginGetUserProfile(new GetUserProfileOptions { IncludeEntities = true, SkipStatus = false });

            var dResponse = _serializerService.Deserialize(service.Response.Response);
```

Comment: Show the code you're using to parse json

Comment: so when you debug, what is inside service.Response.Response?

Answer (score 0):

Full example here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/676313/Twitter-API-v-with-OAuth

Verify_Credentials API: We can have a look at the description of this API over https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials

Search API: We can have a look at the description of this API over https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets

Statuses/Update API: We can have a look at the description of this API over https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update

Request_Token API: We can have a look at the description of this API over https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth/request_token

Authorize API: We can have a look at the description of this API over https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/get/oauth/authorize

Comment: Don't I need to pass the access token and access token secret here?